# Implementing If-Modified-Since client-side caching on jquery-stream plugin

Tags: jquery, json, caching, http-streaming, jqxhr

I've got a use case that requires streaming JSON from a server, and now I'm looking at caching the responses. Unlike JQuery's .ajax function, the .stream function provided by jquery-stream doesn't seem to have support for the IfModified HTTP header. I've managed to alter the source to set the If-Modified-Since header, but I'm not sure how to access the client-side cache to use the cached response instead of the server response. Currently, jquery-stream detects the 304 (Not Modified) and then closes the stream, leaving the responseText on the xhr object blank. Is there a way to manually access the client-side cache, perhaps with the data() function?

If I find out the answer I'll have a go at implementing it and submit the changes to the jquery-stream project.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm wondering why you are concerend about client-side caching of long-held request. I forced a stream request not to be cached by the browser by appending a timestamp parameter. [prepareURL function](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-stream/source/browse/tags/1.2/src/main/webapp/jquery.stream.js?r=197#724) does it.

Because iframe and xdr transport cannot send request header, your implementation cannot be applied in general even though it works with xhr transport. Unfortunately.

Thanks for your opinion.

-- Donghwan

Comment: So the use case is I need to create a JSON document from a long-running process that will gradually return results. I'm using a streaming implementation to send JSON down the wire once its ready, so that by the time the request is finished, the entire document has arrived. However, this document will be unchanged for several minutes before I need to re-generate it, so I was planning on using If-Modified-Since to let the browser know nothing had changed, in the event the client refreshes their page with a given time limit.